# How to use HTTP POST request with the accounts-ui package in Meteor for a simple third party login

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor, user-accounts

I am trying to create a web app using meteor. I am hoping to use the app on my college campus and I wanted to use the college's authentication service so students could login with their college email address and password.  I need to query (with HTTP POST request) https://www.bowdoin.edu/apps/mobile/login.php to get a 0 indicating incorrect user info, or anything else to indicate the user can successful log in. I would like to use the meteor accounts-ui styling and login format and simply authenticate using the POST request. I also want to keep the functionality that allows users to have an id associated with their email address so any user content in the app will stay associated with that user when they log in again. I would like this to be implemented in a way that uses as much code from the accounts-base and accounts-password packages meteor has. The only unique login feature in this case is a post request compared to the Oauth typical of other services.

Comment: Got any example attempts to post for a starting point? Always helps to post what you've tried when asking a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Meteor's built in Accounts package, I think your college's authentication service needs to support OAuth. Per http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice:

> **Meteor.loginWithExternalService([options], [callback])**
>
> These functions initiate the login process with an external service (eg:
> Facebook, Google, etc), using OAuth. When called they open a new
> pop-up window that loads the provider's login page. Once the user has
> logged in with the provider, the pop-up window is closed and the
> Meteor client logs in to the Meteor server with the information
> provided by the external service.

See that section of the docs and try to build your own *accounts-bowdoin* package similar to the examples (accounts-github, etc.); see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/d477c8d03bb078f7e8e85dbe4b51db7ae5689573/packages/github and https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/d477c8d03bb078f7e8e85dbe4b51db7ae5689573/packages/accounts-github for example.